# Protractor with Cucumber, a failed expect is reported correctly but a passed expect times out

Tags: timeout, protractor, chai

I am testing with Protractor, Cucumber and Chai/Chai-as-promised. The following line of code is not giving me the behaviour I'm expecting;

```
expect(settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model")).eventually.equal(table.hashes()[0].description);
```

If I send the expect portion to console.log I get a valid answer ('Bambola');

```
settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model")
```

The 'table.hashes()[0].description' also contains 'Bambola'. If I run the test, I get;

```
function timed out after 5000 milliseconds
```

(I have tried extending the timeout with an env.js entry, it simply takes longer to report the timeout)

If I manually update the value of the description so the expect fails (adding 'failme'), I get what appears to be a valid assertion error;

```
AssertionError: expected 'Bambola' to equal 'Bambolafailme'
```

So why does an apparent successful assertion just time out instead of passing? I also tried;

```
expect(settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model")).eventually.equal(table.hashes()[0].description).then(console.log);
```

And that also logged 'Bambola'.

Comment: you must return the promise : `return expect(settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model")).eventually.equal(table.hashes()[0].description);`

Answer (score 0):

It could be an error in your code. From what I see you forgot to add the `.to` when you do the `expect`. See the [protractor-cookbook](https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/protractor-typescript-cucumber/stepdefinitions/calcSteps.ts#L24) for an example. This is an example for CucumberJS and Typescript, but the concept with `.to` should be the same.

Secondly you can choose between `callbacks` and `promises` for the `expect`s in CucumberJS.

If you use `callbacks` your `expect`s should be (if the `callback` is called `done`)

```
expect(settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model"))
    .to.eventually.equal(table.hashes()[0].description).and.notify(done);
```

If you use `promisses` your `expect`s should be

```
return expect(settingsRolesPage.mainRoleDescription.getAttribute("ng-reflect-model"))
    .to.eventually.equal(table.hashes()[0].description);
```